# Elastic Beanstalk Log Rotation to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a Node application on Elastic Beanstalk.  Our app generates a few log files.  I have successfully configured Elastic Beanstalk to rotate these logs and publish them to S3.

My problem is that the rotated logs are not deleted after being published to S3.  This means that sometimes the same files are published to S3 multiple times.  Standard Elastic Beanstalk logs do not seem to have this problem.

Logs are rotated hourly by means of a `conf` file in `/etc/logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.hourly/` and another `conf` file in `/etc/cron.hourly/`.

Logs are published to S3 by means of a `conf` file in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/publishlogs.d/`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OP here, my premise was wrong.  Turns out this happens with all logs, including standard Elastic Beanstalk logs, so seems to be the intended behavior.